# How to Implement a server side push with Java spring JSF and jquery in a Web application

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsf-2

How can I Implement a server side push with Java spring JSF and jquery in a web application in-order to retrieve real time updates from server as and when a update happens?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is reverse ajax http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/reverse-ajax/configuration.html

Comment: Unfortunately DWR does not explain the server side push correctly in their examples and their examples does not include dynamic updates from server to front-end without a user interaction

Comment: I think server side push does not have a good implementation yet, I did a POC with ICEFACES it worked I could not find the code other wise I would have shared with you, I had this link to my docs you might want to have look at this too  https://github.com/ceefour/jsfajaxpush